# Openlayer 3 - Clustering different layers

Tags: openlayers, markerclusterer

Im new in Openlayer3 so excuse me if Im writing somethings wrong.
Im working with clustering strategy. 
I have several types of objects to show on map and every types has to be clustered.
For Example I have to show cars and trucks.

FIRST QUESTION: To show two different types of objects, Is multi source the only way or I can use one source and then categorize the objects?

For my first try, Im using multi source as code below:

```
var clusterSourceTrucks = new ol.source.Cluster({
    distance: parseInt(20, 10),
    source: new ol.source.Vector({features: [pp1, pp2, pp3]})
  });

var clusterSourceCar = new ol.source.Cluster({
    distance: parseInt(20, 10),
    source: new ol.source.Vector({features: [ll1, ll2, ll3]})
  });
```

I then build a Factory Method using the base code on OpenLayer Examples Page:

```
var styleCache = {};
  function factoryClusteringLayers(name,source,clusterData)
  {
    var clustersLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
      source: source,
      style: function(feature) {
        var size = feature.get('features').length;
        var style = undefined;
        if (styleCache[name] !== undefined)
            style = styleCache[name][size];
        if (!style) {
          style = new ol.style.Style({
            image: new ol.style.Icon({
              anchorOrigin: 'top-left',
              anchor: [0.5, 0.5],
              anchorXUnits: 'pixels',
              anchorYUnits: 'pixels',
              opacity: 0.75,
              src: 'images/'+clusterData.image,
              scale : clusterData.scale,
            }),
            text: new ol.style.Text({
              font: '16px serif',
              text: size.toString(),
              offsetX: 10,
              offsetY: 12,
              fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                color: clusterData.color
              })
            })
          });
          styleCache[name] = style;
        }
        return style;
      }
    });
    return clustersLayer;
  }

var truckLayer  = factoryClusteringLayers('trucks',clusterSourceTrucks,{image : 'truck.png',scale:0.3, color: '#FFFFFF'});
  var carLayer    = factoryClusteringLayers('cars',clusterSourceCar,{image : 'car.png',scale:0.03,'color':'#000000'});

  var objectLayers = [truckLayer, carLayer];
```

This code works perfectly and the single types of object merge correctly.

Unfortunally, when I zoom out, the two (altredy merged) icons overlaps one over another.
I want to merge them too to create an unique object (with a new image/icon/shape) with the sum of the totals of the two cluster and then create a tooltip with the information about content.

Suppose to have 4 cars and 3 trucks.
Zomming out the new objects will show 7 has number. I click on the point and a tooltip will show:
4: cars
3: truck

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at this example to display differents features in a cluster: http://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/examples/map/map.clustering.html

When selecting a cluster it springs apart to display features that's in.